# ASP.NET MVC4 Text Input Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building an extensive web application that has dozens of places that requires the end user to add a comment and looking for the best way to abstract a partial view that renders a modal dialog for the comment and then re-binds back to the model.

For instance, a user adds an allergy to a patient profile, then removes it.  A comment is required when removed, and we store that comment in a RemovalReason property on the allergy model.

Has anyone ever coded for something like this in bulk?  My modal code looks similar like this

```
    @model string

    <div id="text-input-modal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3 id="modalLabel">
        Text Input
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x)
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-text-input-submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.btn-text-input-submit').click(function () {
                $('#text-input-modal form').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I cannot see your form inside #text-input-modal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

missing form tag,

```
<form id="text-input-modal">
 <div class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3 id="modalLabel">
        Text Input
    </h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x)
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-text-input-submit">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Good Luck!